# BizTalk Server 2009 basic authentication to Ruby on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx, biztalk, basic-authentication

I have a Rails website that allows an authenticated client to post XML to a specific URL. In this particular instance, the post request is coming from a BizTalk 2009 server. Rails keeps responding with 401 Unauthorized and I'm not sure why.

The authentication on the Rails side is handled by Restful Authentication via HTTP basic auth. I have tested posting XML to the production site using curl and the credentials of the client in question and it appears to work fine. The owner of the BizTalk server and I have verified the credentials and the URL.

Is there something particular about the way BizTalk handles its basic authentication? Or is there something weird with Rails or Restful Auth? Any ideas? The web server on the Rails side is Nginx with Passenger 3.

Comment: I'm sure you've seen this: http://kentweare.blogspot.com/2009/06/adventures-with-http-adapter-and-yahoo.html Also, are you looking at what BT is sending with fiddler?

Comment: The problem is with authentication, not the post parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What credentials are you using to authenticate?  It would need to be that of the BizTalk service account that is sending the request.  What adapter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the problem went away undetected. I had to modify the auth code to deal with authentication problems in Internet Explorer (see http://rails_security.lighthouseapp.com/projects/15332/tickets/5-using-http-basic-authentication-with-ie-not-working). It's possible that BizTalk would have the same problem, but I can't verify.

It's also possible that the owner of the BizTalk server updated the credentials used to contact our service, but again I can't verify.

As we have bigger fish to fry, it's not worth it to us to track down the exact issue since all is working fine now. Of course that could change and I'll dig deeper and perhaps update this thread.